# Count divs with custom attribute by reference

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count divs which are created dynamically by javascript by their category attribute and put the result into list with corresponding category attribute value. I think It's not working for because I have problem capturing attribute value in function. Can anyone help me? Thx

```
<div class='item' category='1'></div>
<div class='item' category='2'></div>
<div class='item' category='1'></div>
<div class='item' category='1'></div>

<ul id='list'>
  <li class='counter' category='1'>Category 1</li>
  <li class='counter' category='2'>Category 2</li>
</ul>

function count_category(){
        if($('#list').length>0){
            $('.counter').each(function(i, obj){
                var count = $('.item[category='+obj.category+']')
                var result = count.length;
                $(this).append('<span>'+result+'</span>');
            });
        }
    }   

    $(document).ajaxComplete(count_category);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute value use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - `obj.category` returns `undefined`

```
var count = $('.item[category="' + $(this).attr('category') + '"]')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6zzq7/)